# PhoneGap Android app not displaying pdf data

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have a PhoneGap app for Android which I am trying to run in the Android emulator. The app has a simple html page which has a button. On click, the button calls a RESTful webservice using javascript XMLHttpRequest and the service returns back base 64 encoded data for a pdf. Then from the javascript function, I try to load the pdf data in my html page in the app as below

```
document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + pdfData.childNodes[0].data;
```

But this does nothing. The data is returned correctly and I checked the logs for it. But the pdf is not displayed at all. Any idea what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Android you not show pdf file in Webview. Have some solution to view pdf file in Android:

1. Use google pdf view

   mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo_pdfFile);
2. Download pdf file and view by pdf reader in device. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368788/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-android)
3. (My solution) I parse pdf file to image and store onto server and i only download and view image directly.(It have bit complex, but you can view pdf, docx, xls,..). Example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578889/pdf-to-image-convert-high-size-image)